# how get to embedded array in mongoose

Tags: arrays, json, mongodb, mongoose

I have an object category and inside it, I have an array of subcategory and inside that array, I have another array of products how I can get those product using the two _ID of category and subcategory

Comment: add your code and schema to the question

Comment: @MohammadYaserAhmadi thank you soo much i found the solution by using the method Array.prototype.find()  that return that object "product" that I'm looking for